# How can I server multiple paths on same service through one Ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, server, routes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I am working on a GKE cluster. I have a simple server running. There are three routes on the server.

```
route 1 - / 
route 2 - /ping
route 3 - /health
```

These paths return 200 response with generic but different "ok" messages.

This is what my ingress yaml looks like -

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basic-ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.simple.com
    secretName: simple-server-tls
  rules:
    - host: www.simple.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /ping
          backend:
            serviceName: simple-server
            servicePort: 8080
```

I have my server exposed as a load balancer. I can access all three routes using loadbalancer as 
`https://<loadbalancer_ip>:8080/
https://<loadbalancer_ip>:8080/ping
https://<loadbalancer_ip>:8080/health`

However, when trying to use an ingress, I only receive a 200 response on `https://www.simple.com/ping`
The other two routes i.e. `https://www.simple.com/health` and `https://www.simple.com/` return `default backend - 404 error`.

I can confirm that the server is running and is serving requests perfectly and I have given ingress enough time(upwards of 30 minutes) to finish setting-up. `https://www.simple.com/healthz returns "OK"`.

I think I am making a mistake in configuring the ingress correctly. Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

I cannot provide the ingress logs as I am noticing that `kubectl describe ingress/basic-ingress` returns the  error `Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource` However, kubectl get ingress returns `basic-ingress   www.simple.com   <ingress_ip>   80, 443   31m`

Comment: You're rewriting all URLs as /. Remove the rewrite-target annotation, and it should work.

Comment: I did try that. I had my ingress configured with `path /health`. If I was rewriting the URL, I should have received the response for `path /`. However in that case, I was receiving 404 on `path /` and `path /ping`. Only `path /health` was working.

Comment: If you configured the ingress for `/health`, all the other urls will be unmapped, so getting 404 is expected. The path is a prefix, anything starting with that path will be proxied. With `/`, you're sending everything, but rewriting  them as `/`. Try without the rewrite annotation.

Comment: I did try it just now. This solution didn't work. I received 200 on `https://www.simple.com` and 404 on `https://www.simple.com/ping`

Comment: I traced my outgoing HTTP requests and I can confirm that my requests are going out as `GET https://www.simple.com/` and `GET https://www.simple.com/ping`

Comment: You should look at nginx access logs, see what it is trying to do.

Comment: checked the logs. Nothing out of the ordinary. Events say Normal Add and Normal Create

Comment: I think there has to be some wild card right? like /*?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue. You need to add a wild card to the path. I only had `/` in my path and hence it was rejecting (read throwing 404 error) for all my other urls. I added `/*` and removed `the rewrite-target annotation` as @bserdar correctly suggested and it worked. Link to the issue on github that helped a lot - `https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1120`

Comment: Your ingress is GKE ingress. It is not nginx ingress. The rules are different for each ingress implementation. Since it is not nginx, the rewrite-target should also be unnecessary, as afaik, it does not apply to GKE ingress.