# How to configure Ingress in GKE/GCP to multiple path point to the same backend service?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to prevent unsafe requested to reach my application running in GCP GKE with Google Ingress (not nginx) and trying to do this using path rules.
I know nginx Ingress can configure paths using regex but I don know the best way to do with Google Ingress.
Right now I am just duplicating the same rules change the path prefix like this:

```
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: my-api-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: my-api-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /auth
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: my-api-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /admin
        pathType: Prefix
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Everything you're looking for is covered in [this](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts#pm-constraints) document. As GKE ingress is essentially a GCP Load Balancer, the `path` key is using a `url-map` to configure and route the traffic to what you've specified in the config. As you'd be able to see there, regexs are not allowed in `Path` keys.

One option if you're using Helm is to make use of the templates to generate this automatically from a variable. Given the following variable in your `values.yaml` file:

```
paths:
 - name: /api
 - name: /admin
 - name: /auth
```

Then in your ingress YAML definition you can do the following:

```
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
{{ range $paths := .Values.paths }}
      - backend:
          service:
            name: my-api-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: {{ .name }}
        pathType: Prefix
{{ end }}
```

Comment: Hmm but if Im not using Helm the way that Im defining is the best approach than,right? I will take a look at the doc you mentioned, but I know that I cant use regex in Paths. Thank you!

Comment: I think so, unfortunately GKE ingress is lagging way behind in certain features compared to NGINX and some other providers

Answer (score 0):

In **GKE** ingress **regex** is not allowed in paths as it is using the `url-map` to configure GCP Load Balancers. Only wildcard allowed in paths is `*`. We cannot use any other wildcards in the path key.

So you can try like this

```
  spec:
      rules:
      - http:
          paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: my-api-service
                port:
                  number: 80
            path: /*
            pathType: Prefix
```

**(or)**

You can use the default backend services to route the traffic to the single service like in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#default_backend)

```
   spec:
     defaultBackend:
       service:
        name: my-api-service
        port:
         number: 80
```

You can give a try by changing the annotation like mentioned in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55863247/k8s-error-running-load-balancer-syncing-routine).

There are other similar SO's [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58313480/how-can-i-server-multiple-paths-on-same-service-through-one-ingress) [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54274992/k8s-ingress-rule-for-multiple-paths-in-same-backend-service).

Comment: Actually I didint want to allow every paths to my-api-service. I was trying to filter only some specific path routes.